# How to extract attribute values from XML element using XML Extractor in U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

How can I extract attribute value from XML element using [XML Extractor](https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats) in U-SQL for my Azure data lake analytic job.

**Update: More details about the issue**

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testelement testatr="xyz">
</testelement>
```

Here is my U-SQL Script:

```
DECLARE @testfile string = "sample2.xml";
@logText =
EXTRACT log string            
FROM @testfile
USING Extractors.Tsv();

@gethID = SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Evaluate(@logText.log, "testelement/attribute::testatr").ElementAt(0) AS siteName FROM @logText;
OUTPUT @gethID TO "result.out" USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

After debugging I observed, exception occurred when Load method of XPath class try to load:

```
"<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8?>"
```

Here is an exception:

```
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException' occurred in Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.dll
Additional information: {"diagnosticCode":195887111,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"User","errorId":"E_RUNTIME_USER_EXPRESSIONEVALUATION","message":"Error while evaluating expression Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Evaluate(log, \"testelement/attribute::testatr\").ElementAt(0)","description":"Inner exception from user expression: '1.0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '\"' or '''. Line 1, position 15.\nCurrent row dump: \tlog:\t\"<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8?>\"
\n","resolution":"","helpLink":"","details":"==== Caught exception System.Xml.XmlException\n\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
\n   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
\n   at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Load(String xml)
\n   at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Evaluate(String xml, String xpath)
\n   at ___Scope_Generated_Classes___.SqlFilterTransformer_2.Process(IRow row, IUpdatableRow output) in c:\\workarea\\bswbigdata\\USQLAppForLogs\\USQLAppForLogs\\bin\\Debug\\A06D46624BBA798\\ReadBlobs.usql.Debug_A54F30D359F939C7\\__ScopeCodeGen__.dll.cs:line 53","internalDiagnostics":""}
```

**Update 2:**

After using quoting:false I am getting another exception:

```
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException' occurred in Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.dll
Additional information: {"diagnosticCode":195887111,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"User","errorId":"E_RUNTIME_USER_EXPRESSIONEVALUATION","message":"Error while evaluating expression Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Evaluate(log, \"testelement/attribute::testatr\").ElementAt(0)","description":"Inner exception from user expression: Root element is missing.\nCurrent row dump: \tlog:\t\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\"
\n","resolution":"","helpLink":"","details":"==== Caught exception System.Xml.XmlException\n\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
\n   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
\n   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
\n   at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Load(String xml)
\n   at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XPath.Evaluate(String xml, String xpath)
\n   at ___Scope_Generated_Classes___.SqlFilterTransformer_2.Process(IRow row, IUpdatableRow output) in c:\\workarea\\bswbigdata\\USQLAppForLogs\\USQLAppForLogs\\bin\\Debug\\A06D46624BBA798\\ReadBlobs.usql.Debug_A54F30D359F939C7\\__ScopeCodeGen__.dll.cs:line 53","internalDiagnostics":""}
```

Answer (score 3):

You identify the values with XPath expressions. An attribute is queried with `@attr_name` (or the full axis expression `attribute::attr_name`).

UPDATE based on question update:

It looks like that the parser somehow gets confused by the " inside the XML declaration. I see that you use the built-in Tsv() extractor that per default currently processes " inside a field as a quoting character and then drops it. This is a bug we are planning on fixing.

Until then I suggest that you use `Extractors.Tsv(quoting:false)`.

Also please make sure that your XML document does not contain any CR/LF if you are using any of the built-in text extractors (`Extractors.*`) and that it does not contain a tab-value if you are using .Tsv.

If your XML will contain CR and/or LF then you will have to use a custom extractor to use a different row-delimiter. If you need to do that, please leave me a message, because I am currently tracking such requests to see what we can improve in the built-in extractors.

If your file only contains a single XML document (as opposed to several rows of XML documents) I would suggest to use the XML extractor that is also part of the XML sample on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried this approach but got an exception. Please see updated questions details.

Comment: Thanks Jamil. I updated my answer based on your additional details.

Answer (score 0):

On the new error message: It looks like the XML document contains a CR or LF or both after the XML declaration and thus the Tsv() extractor splits the XML document. See my comment in the previous answer:

> Also please make sure that your XML document does not contain any CR/LF if you are using any of the built-in text extractors (Extractors.*) and that it does not contain a tab-value if you are using .Tsv.
>
> If your XML will contain CR and/or LF then you will have to use a custom extractor to use a different row-delimiter. If you need to do that, please leave me a message, because I am currently tracking such requests to see what we can improve in the built-in extractors.

Comment: So I guess, currently, I don't have any solution in default extractors to get attribute value from XML that contains CR/LF, right?

Comment: Correct. You should instead use the extractors provided in the sample library. Or remove the CR/LF (if they are so called "insignificant whitespace" in the XML).

Comment: Hi @michael-rys, Could you please give me some example for xaml extractors provided in the sample library for extracting attribute value from XML? I can see example for extracting element value but not for attribute value.

Comment: Hi Jamil... did you try to write `@name` to reference the attribute (instead of `name` to reference the element)?